# Pytest - no tests ran

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I'm using pytest and selenium. When I try run my test script:

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from pages import *
from locators import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

class RegisterNewInstructor:
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.get("http://mytest.com")

    def test_01_clickBecomeTopButtom(self):
        page = HomePage(self.driver)
        page.click_become_top_button()
        self.assertTrue(page.check_instructor_form_page_loaded())

    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
```

The message shown is: **no tests ran in 0.84 seconds**

Could someone help me run this simple test?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the [`pytest` test conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery), your class should start with `Test` to be automatically picked up by the test discovery mechanism. Call it `TestRegisterNewInstructor` instead.

Or, subclass the `unittest.TestCase`:

```
import unittest

class RegisterNewInstructor(unittest.TestCase):
    # ...
```

Also keep in mind that the .py test script itself must begin with `test_` or end with `_test` in its filename.

Comment: I'm not sure as to why this answer has had upvotes and is accepted. OP's post was about the `pytest` library, not `unittest`. Maybe I'm wrong. Are they both related under the bonnet? @alecxe @AlSweigart @RafaelC.

Comment: Pytest will also include a class's methods to test if they subclass unittest.TestCase. I believe this is to make it cross-compatible to ease migration from one to the other.

Answer (score 29):

As simple as it looks:

1. Make sure that your **file name** matches the pattern: `test_*.py` or `*_test.py`.
2. Make sure that your **function name** starts with the `test` prefix.

Find more about the pytest conventions [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

Answer (score 1):

try add @classmethod on the top of setUP and tearDown.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem in the pytest.ini file where I had pyton_files = tests_*.py. Removed the 's' and everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute the class itself? 
 I don't see in this code you are showing that you call the class or definitions to run. 
 
For example, in python you run a class or definition like this:

```
class Hello():
    # __init__ is a definition runs itself. 
    def __init__(self): 
        print('Hello there')
        # Call another definition. 
        self.andBye()

    # This definition should be calles in order to be executed. 
    def andBye(self):
        print('Goodbye')

# Run class 
Hello()
```

Comment: Actually, `pytest` has automatic test discovery.

Answer (score 0):

If you use conda environment, don't forget to activate it!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message as shown below

```
$ pytest -q -rP

no tests ran in 0.10s
```

Because even though my test file name is `my_test_ex1.py` in `my_tests/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 |-my_tests
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  └-my_test_ex1.py # Here
 |-pytest.ini
 ...
```

I did not set `my_test_*.py` to [python_files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=python_files#confval-python_files) in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) as shown below. *By default, Pytest can run the files `test_*.py` and `*_test.py` according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files) if you do not set `python_files` in `pytest.ini`:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = core.settings
# python_files = my_test_*.py # Here
```

So, I set `my_test_*.py` to `python_files` as shown below, then I could run the tests in `my_test_ex1.py`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210149/pytest-doesnt-run-any-test/77074662#77074662) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830654/is-there-a-way-to-run-all-pytest-cases-from-multiple-folders/77028618#77028618) explain it more:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = core.settings
python_files = my_test_*.py # Here
```