# pytest doesn't run any test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

pytest doesn't run any tests and it is not clear why. I tried to use --debug but didn't get any valuable information. It is completely not clear how to debug this sort of issues with pytest. (Looks like some issue with pytest configuration / env variables / test names patterns?)

Example of test file:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.sanity
def test_me():
    """I'm a test."""

    assert True
```

But pytest doesn't run any test, why?

```
$ pytest
================================================== test session starts ===================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/qawizard/pytest-hell, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.15.0, timeout-1.2.0
collected 1 item s

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Exit: Done! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================== no tests ran in 0.13 seconds ==============================================
```

Comment: did you register that marker in `pytest.ini` ?
do you have any OTHER configuration in `pytest.ini`?
could you rerun `pytest -lsvvv` to see extra verbose output?
do you have `conftest.py` with some custom configuration?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To determine why tests are not running, these steps are useful:

1. Verify that all files with test cases have a 'test_' prefix.
2. Verify that all test case names also have a 'test_' prefix.
3. Verify that you have created `pytest.ini` file in the root directory.
4. Verify that you have `__init__.py` file in all directories/sub-directories of the project.

Answer (score 4):

You need all tests to start with `test_` but also you need to tell Pytest exact which files to look for:

```py
# pytest.ini

[pytest]

DJANGO_SETTIONS_MODULE = myproject.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py
```

Comment: What is DJANGO_SETTIONS_MODULE and why we use it?

Answer (score 2):

For me my class name didn't start with test.

my code was

```py
class MainTest:
    ...

    def test_properties(self):
        ...
```

This wont work because pytest will assume this class shouldn't be included.
Changing to this did it for me.

```py
class TestMain:
    ...

    def test_properties(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, there is `apples/apple.py` as shown below:

```
project
 |-pytest.ini
 └-apples
    |-__init__.py
    └-apple.py # Here
```

Then, there is `apple(self)` in `Apple` class in `apples/apple.py` as shown below:

```py
# "apples/apple.py"

import pytest

class Apple:
    def apple(self):
        assert True
```

Now, with this `pytest.ini` below, `apple(self)` cannot be run because by default, Pytest can run the files `test_*.py` and `*_test.py`, the classes prefixed with `Test` and the functions prefixed with `test` instead of `apple.py` file, `Apple` class and `apple(self)` function according to [python_files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files), [python_classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_classes) and [python_functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_functions) and by default, Pytest can run any folders like `apples`:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
```

So, with this `pytest.ini` below, `apple(self)` can be run:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
python_files = apple.py
python_classes = Apple
python_functions = apple
```

In addition, by default, you can run all the tests in `apples/test_1.py`, `apples/oranges/test_2.py`, `bananas/test_1.py` and `banana/kiwis/test_2.py` as shown below because as I said above, by default, Pytest can run any folders like `apples`, `oranges`, `bananas` and `kiwis`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830654/is-there-a-way-to-run-all-pytest-cases-from-multiple-folders/77028618#77028618) explains it:

```
project
 |-pytest.ini
 |-apples
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-test_1.py # Here
 |  └-oranges
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-test_2.py # Here
 └-bananas
    |-__init__.py
    |-test_1.py # Here
    └-kiwis
       |-__init__.py
       └-test_2.py Here
```