# PyCharm PyTest: no test subjects found

Tags: pycharm, pytest

I'm using pytest with pycharm, and I've created a simple test with pycharms `create new test` command: `⌘⇧T`.

The test looks like this

```py
def my_test():
  assert False
```

The issue is, that a common IDE functionality is to jump back from the test code to the test subject using the same command `⌘⇧T`. I find this very useful while practicing TDD.

The problem is, that PyCharm doesn't register what the test subject is, and pops with the error:

> No test subjects found.

I wanted to how to fix this, or if this is just the design of pytest.

Thanks!

---

Edit:
To be clear, the tests run fine, so this is not a duplicate of [PyTest doesn't run any tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210149/pytest-doesnt-run-any-test), the issue is about PyCharm code navigation shortcuts.

Comment: *"a common IDE functionality is to jump back from the test code to the test subject"* actually you are wrong about this because one test can be used to test several different functions so there's no 1:1 correspondence. You can also have several tests for 1 function, so again no 1:1 correspondence. What PyCharm does is include a green arrow in the gutter if a test has the exact name as a function (but that's some smart background IDE processing that doesn't hold under all conditions.)

Comment: Still, my question holds - how can I have it so that pycharm knows what the test subject is?