# Is there a way to run all pytest cases from multiple folders?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Suppose I have `test_case1.py` in folder `A`, and `test_case2.py` in folder `B`. Can I run them together using a single `pytest` command?

Folder structure:

```
projectfolder/A/test_case1.py
projectfolder/B/test_case2.py
```

Answer (score 13):

You can give pytest multiple folders to discover tests in:

```
python -m pytest projectfolder/A projectfolder/B
```

or if you want to use a config file:

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = [
    "projectfolder/A",
    "projectfolder/B",
]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked but if there are suppose 20 folders then its not good to provide 20 different folder names in the command. Is there any other way?

Comment: Im not 100% sure on your project structure, but you might get away with just `python -m pytest projectfolder`. Anothe option could be to create a pytest config file and specify all the paths there: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#configuration-file-formats

Comment: python -m pytest projectfolder worked...thanks

Comment: @Tzane Is there a way to pass different python path each test directory?

Comment: @KingstonX I don't think its possible to change the interpreter on the fly, so the easiest way would be to call them separately like `python310 -m pytest tests310; python312 -m pytest tests312`

Comment: @Tzane Thank you, but I did not ask about changing the Python version. I was asking about changing the PYTHONPATH. Example: pytest PYTHONPATH=src projectfolder/A PYTHONPATH=src/xyz projectfolder/B

Comment: @KingstonX If you don't want to do separate CLI calls (`PYTHONPATH=src python -m pytest ...; PYTHONPATH=src/xyz python -m pytest ...`), making a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/fixtures.html) that modifies `sys.path` at runtime for selected tests is something that I can think of.

Comment: @Tzane Is there a way to save both the test results in one xml, this is what I have now and it is overwritting ```$(RESULTS_DIR)/test-results.xml: $(TEST_FILES)
 mkdir -p $(RESULTS_DIR)
 PYTHONPATH=$(SRC_DIR_1) pytest \
  --cov=$(SRC_DIR_1) \
  --cov-branch \
  --cov-report=xml:$(TEST_RESULTS_DIR)/coverage.xml \
  --cov-report=html:$(RESULTS_DIR)/htmlcov \
  --cov-report=term \
  --cov-report=term-missing \
  --junitxml=$(RESULTS_DIR)/test-results.xml \
  $(TEST_DIR_1); \ 
 PYTHONPATH=$(SRC_DIR_2) pytest ...  --junitxml=$(RESULTS_DIR)/test-results.xml $(TEST_DIR_2);```

Answer (score 0):

You can run all the tests in multiple folders.

Actually by default, you can run all the tests in `tests1/test_1.py`, `tests1/subtests/test_2.py`, `tests2/test_1.py` and `tests2/subtests/test_2.py` as shown below because by default, Pytest can run the files `test_*.py` and `*_test.py`, the classes prefixed with `Test` and the functions prefixed with `test` instead of `apple.py` file, `Apple` class and `apple(self)` function according to [python_files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_files), [python_classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_classes) and [python_functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#confval-python_functions) and by default, Pytest can run any folders like `tests1`, `tests2` and `subtests`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210149/pytest-doesnt-run-any-test/77074662#77074662) explains it:

```
project
 |-pytest.ini
 |-tests1
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-test_1.py # Here
 |  └-subtests
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-test_2.py # Here
 └-tests2
    |-__init__.py
    |-test_1.py # Here
    └-subtests
       |-__init__.py
       └-test_2.py # Here
```

In addition, if you set `tests1` and `tests2/subtests` to [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) in [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini), you can run all the tests except in `tests2/test_1.py`:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = tests1 tests2/subtests # Here
```

And, if the specified `testpaths` below doesn't exist, all the tests are run:

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = my_tests # Doesn't exist
```

In addition, you can run `tests2/subtests/test_2.py` with these commands below according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run):

```
pytest tests2/subtests
```

Or:

```
pytest tests2/subtests/test_2.py
```