# pytest: manually add test to discovered tests

Tags: python, pytest

```
# tests/test_assert.py
@pytest.mark.mymark
def custom_assert():
    assert True
```

How do I force pytest to discover this test?

In general, how do I dynamically add any test to pytest's list of discovered tests, even if they don't fit in the naming convention?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest - no tests ran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363388)

Comment: No. I know about the naming convention. I want to add this test to the discovered tests without renaming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pytest is fairly customisable, but you'll have to look at its extensive [API](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#collection-hooks). Luckily, the code base is statically typed, so you can navigate from functions and classes to other functions and classes fairly easily.

To start off, it pays to understand *how* pytest discovers tests. Recall the [configurable discovery naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions):

```ini
# content of pytest.ini
# Example 1: have pytest look for "check" instead of "test"
[pytest]
python_files = check_*.py
python_classes = Check
python_functions = *_check
```

This implies that, for example, the value to `python_functions` is used somewhere to filter out functions that are *not* considered as test functions. Do a [quick search on the pytest repository](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apytest-dev%2Fpytest++language%3APython+python_functions&type=code&l=Python) to see [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/723035be7f6abd339bba233ad05f9db41202a904/src/_pytest/python.py#L387-L389):

```py
class PyCollector(PyobjMixin, nodes.Collector):
    def funcnamefilter(self, name: str) -> bool:
        return self._matches_prefix_or_glob_option("python_functions", name)
```

`PyCollector` is a base class for [pytest `Module`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#module) objects, and `module_: pytest.Module` has an [`obj` property](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/723035be7f6abd339bba233ad05f9db41202a904/src/_pytest/python.py#L305-L318) which is the `types.ModuleType` object itself. Along with access to the `funcnamefilter::name` parameter, you can make a subclass of `pytest.Module`, `pytest.Package`, and `pytest.Class` to override `funcnamefilter` to accept functions decorated your custom `@pytest.mark.mymark` decorator as test functions:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import types
import typing as t

import pytest


# Static-type-friendliness
if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _pytest.python import PyCollector

    class _MarkDecorated(t.Protocol):
        pytestmark: list[pytest.Mark]

        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> None:
            """Test function callback method"""

else:
    PyCollector: t.TypeAlias = object


def _isPytestMarkDecorated(obj: object) -> t.TypeGuard[_MarkDecorated]:

    """
    Decorating `@pytest.mark.mymark` over a function results in this:

    >>> @pytest.mark.mymark
    ... def f() -> None:
    ...     pass
    ...
    >>> f.pytestmark
    [Mark(name='mymark', args=(), kwargs={})]

    where `Mark` is `pytest.Mark`.

    This function provides a type guard for static typing purposes.
    """

    if (
        callable(obj)
        and hasattr(obj, "pytestmark")
        and isinstance(obj.pytestmark, list)
    ):
        return True
    return False

class _MyMarkMixin(PyCollector):
    def funcnamefilter(self, name: str) -> bool:
        underlying_py_obj: object = self.obj
        assert isinstance(underlying_py_obj, (types.ModuleType, type))
        func: object = getattr(underlying_py_obj, name)
        if _isPytestMarkDecorated(func) and any(
            mark.name == "mymark" for mark in func.pytestmark
        ):
            return True
        return super().funcnamefilter(name)


class MyMarkModule(_MyMarkMixin, pytest.Module):
    pass
```

The last thing to do is to configure pytest to use your `MyMarkModule` rather than `pytest.Module` when collecting test modules. You can do this with the [per-directory plugin module file `conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins), where you would override the hook [`pytest.pycollect.makemodule`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_pycollect_makemodule) (please see pytest's [implementation](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/723035be7f6abd339bba233ad05f9db41202a904/src/_pytest/python.py#L227-L232) on how to write this properly):

```py
# conftest.py
import typing as t
from <...> import MyMarkModule

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import pathlib
    import pytest


def pytest_pycollect_makemodule(
    module_path: pathlib.Path, parent: object
) -> pytest.Module | None:
    if module_path.name != "__init__.py":
        return MyMarkModule.from_parent(parent, path=module_path)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
```

Now you can run `pytest <your test file>` and you should see all `@pytest.mark.mymark` functions run as test functions, regardless of whether they're named according to the `pytest_functions` configuration setting.

---

This is a start on what you need to do, and *can* do with pytest. You'll have to do this with `pytest.Class` and `pytest.Package` as well, if you're planning on using `@pytest.mark.mymark` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

## Change naming convention

[Pytest > Changing naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions)

> You can configure different naming conventions by setting the python_files, python_classes and python_functions in your configuration file. Here is an example:
>
> ```ini
> # content of pytest.ini
> # Example 1: have pytest look for "check" instead of "test"
> [pytest]
> python_files = check_*.py 
> python_classes = Check 
> python_functions = *_check
> ```
>
> This would make pytest look for tests in files that match the check_* .py glob-pattern, Check prefixes in classes, and functions and methods that match *_check.
> You can check for multiple glob patterns by adding a space between the patterns.

So, in your case, you need this configuration in `pytest.ini`:

```ini
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
python_functions = *_assert
```

Comment: This only works for a single function. What if I have a hundred methods all named differently that I can't change?

Comment: "You can check for multiple glob patterns by adding a space between the patterns." add names in the python_functions config like: `what_foo example_bar assert_* *_assert spam_eggs`. It's boilerplate, but it's how you force pytest to discover those functions.

Comment: What if the method is inside a closure? What if I'm generating the method dynamically? Editing the config file is fine if you are sticking to another naming convention, not for adding specific methods in general.

Comment: "What if the method is inside a closure" How do you expect anything to run a function defined in a function? IMO, you are looking for a miracle, sorry.

Comment: A function defined inside a function is still an object, there's no reason why I shouldn't be able to manipulate it further. For example, the ward framework allows to append arbitrary functions to the collected tests, even ones inside closures.

Comment: @SomeGuy Can you provide an example, please?